# In the definition of the strong operator topology on $L(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$, why must $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be Banach spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

In [Folland](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471317160), the strong operator topology is defined as the topology on $L(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$ induced by the evaluation maps $\{T \mapsto Tx\}_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$, where $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$ are Banach spaces. In terms of convergence, we have that $T_\alpha \rightarrow T$ in the strong topology iff $T_\alpha x \rightarrow Tx$ in the norm topology of $\mathcal{Y}$ for all $x \in \mathcal{X}$. My question is, why must $\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y}$ be Banach spaces? The "net characterization" still holds if they are considered merely normed vector spaces, I'm pretty sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any reason why you can't make this definition for the bounded linear operators between normed vector spaces.   Of course any bounded linear map from normed vector space $X$ to normed vector space $Y$ extends uniquely to a bounded linear map from the completion of $X$ to the completion of $Y$, so the extra generality probably doesn't get you much.  When your spaces are complete, analysis is much more convenient (e.g. you have the Baire Category Theorem and its consequences).

Comment: I thought this was the reason! I was confused because Folland usually tries to be as general as he can be. Thank you!